# Convert docx/doc to pdf with comments markup

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, ms-word, docx

I'd like to programmatically (using Node.js) convert a doc or a docx file to pdf while keeping its comments just like what MS word does on exporting a doc/docx file as a PDF. Is there a way to do so?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkY3q.png]

I've tried

- Microsoft's Graph API but couldn't find a way to include comments. It just converts the file to PDF, that's it
- [docx-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf) which uses [Mammoth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth) behind the scenes but it converts the file to HTML, thus the comments' styling is really ugly

Comment: You can, within Word, print to pdf, which will preserve comments if printing markup is chosen.